# Command to affect every player except myself

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm making a spellbook in Minecraft, and I want to make a spell that affects everyone in a certain radius except me, so I just made this:

```
/effect @a[r=10,type=!@p] 15 60
```

It doesn't seem to work. What is wrong with it?

Comment: We don't know, what doesn't it do that you want it to do?  Is it affecting you when you don't want it to?  Is not affecting anyone?

Comment: For starters it should be `@a` not `@A`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `rm`, e.g. `/effect @a[r=10,rm=1] 15 60`.  Then it will only work on players at least one block away from you, so not you.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `/effect @a[r=10,name=!YourPlayerName] 15 60`

If you want to use it with different playernames, you can do this:

- First make a new scoreboard objective (`/scoreboard objectives add someName dummy`)
- Then set the score for all players to 1 (`/scoreboard players set @a someName 1`)
- Then set the score for you to 0 (`/scoreboard players set @p someName 0`)
- Then use this command to give the effect: `/effect @a[r=10,score_someName_min=1] 15 60`

Comment: I think this is the better answer, as it works for command blocks as well, and allows further options.